# Se ha producido un error 424 - Se requiere un objeto VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Cuando intento cargo un cuadro combinado me sale el siguiente mensaje:

Se ha producido un error 424 - Se requiere un objeto

**Este es el código que utilice:**

```
Sub Cargar_cbo_Unidad()
    Dim Rango As Range
    Dim Celda As Range
    Range("B4").Select
    Set Rango = Worksheets("Unidades").Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    'Cuando utilizo un rango en especifico el código funciona
    Set Rango = Worksheets("Unidades").Range("B4:B6")
     For Each Celda In Rango
        cbo_Unidad.AddItem Celda.Value
    Next Celda
End Sub
```

Comment: Mi otra duda es que almacena Worksheets("Unidades").Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select ya que cada vez que imprimo con Debug.Print me sale Verdadero

Comment: Por favor. no subas una imagen del código. Si subes el código en texto será más facil poder ayudarte

Comment: Listo ya agregué el código

Comment: selection solo no es nada.. que querias poner ahi?

Answer (score 1):

Bienvenido a SO.

Prueba con `Set Rango = Worksheets("Unidades").Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))`, omitiendo el Select. Así asignas el rango a la variable. Por eso, cuando pones un rango específico sí funciona, porque omites el Select

Answer (score 0):

Trabajando con VBA deberías intentar no utilizar nunca las propiedades `.Select` o `.Activate` y siempre cualificar completamente los rangos que utilizas: Libro->hoja->rango

En mi ejemplo verás cómo hacerlo:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Cargar_cbo_Unidad()

    Dim Rango As Range, Celda As Range
    Dim UltimaFila As Long

    'utilizar el with te permite hacer alusión al objeto en el with (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Unidades") con tan sólo poner un punto
    'delante.
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Unidades") 'esto se refiere al libro que contiene el código
        'Lo ideal es que nunca utilices .Select o .Activate y calcules el rango que necesitas. Normalmente se calcula desde abajo
        'porque si tienes celdas en blanco entre medio, se pararía ahí al calcularlo desde arriba.
        UltimaFila = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'esto calcularía la última fila contando desde abajo
        'UltimaFila = .Cells(4, "B").End(xlDown).Row 'esto calcularía la última fila contando desde arriba
        Set Rango = .Range("B4", .Cells(UltimaFila, "B"))
         For Each Celda In Rango
            cbo_Unidad.AddItem Celda.Value
        Next Celda
    End With
End Sub
```